# Check an Excel workbook for broken hyperlinks

Tags: excel

A hyperlink to a named range can become "broken" by deleting the named range. When this happens, clicking on the hyperlink will display a message "Reference isn't valid". Is there any way to automatically search through a workbook to find these broken hyperlinks?

Comment: What do you mean by a "named range" when referring to a hyperlink? If your question is `Can one automatically search for a hyperlink that does not refer to a valid address or target`, yes you can, but you'll need VBA to do so.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is what I mean. Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld. I shouldn't have trouble constructing a VBA solution. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Ron Rosenfeld's advise that I will need to use VBA, I created the following to solve the problem.

```
Public Sub CheckForBrokenLinks()
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim searchSheet As Worksheet
    Dim checkLink As Hyperlink
    Dim testRange As Range

    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    For Each searchSheet In targetWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each checkLink In searchSheet.Hyperlinks
            If Not checkLink.SubAddress = "" Then
                If Not DoesAddressExist(searchSheet, checkLink.SubAddress) Then
                    Debug.Print "I think the following link is broken:"
                    Debug.Print "   Link name: " & checkLink.Name
                    Debug.Print "   Sheet name: " & searchSheet.Name
                    Debug.Print "   Link target: " & checkLink.SubAddress
                    If checkLink.Type = 0 Then
                        Debug.Print "   Link range: " & checkLink.Range.address
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next checkLink
    Next searchSheet
End Sub

Private Function DoesAddressExist(searchSheet As Worksheet, address As String) As Boolean
    Dim testRange As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    Set testRange = searchSheet.Evaluate(address)
    DoesAddressExist = Err.Number = 0
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```